# ValueError in onehotencoding

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, one-hot-encoding

I'm not able to encode this column

```
Sex
male
female
female
female
male
male
male
male
female
female

from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder,OneHotEncoder
labelencoder=LabelEncoder()
X[:,2]=labelencoder.fit_transform(X[:,2])
ohe=OneHotEncoder(categorical_features=X[2])
ohe.fit_transform(X)
```

I'm getting this error.

> could not convert string to float: 'male'

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Please add the full stack trace of error along with some sample data in X.

Comment: Even though you have specified `categorical_features`, the OneHotEncoder will still check the whole X to be numeric.

Comment: ' array = np.array(array, dtype=dtype, order=order, copy=copy)

ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Male''..This is the full error

Comment: @Anesh, what is your goal? To encode `Sex` column as a numerical column or to perform One-Hot-Encoding and end up with two columns: `['male','female']`?

Comment: Iam not able to label encode the gender column.Like Sex=[0,1,0,0,1...]

Comment: Spelling correction and formatted code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Demo:

```
In [6]: df
Out[6]:
      Sex
0    male
1  female
2  female
3  female
4    male
5    male
6    male
7    male
8  female
9  female

In [7]: le = LabelEncoder()

In [8]: df['Sex'] = le.fit_transform(df['Sex'])

In [9]: df
Out[9]:
   Sex
0    1
1    0
2    0
3    0
4    1
5    1
6    1
7    1
8    0
9    0

In [10]: df.dtypes
Out[10]:
Sex    int64
dtype: object
```

Comment: @Anesh, glad i could help :)